# run MATLAB unit tests in parallel

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

In this framework

```
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html?refresh=true
```

I found MATLAB could run test cases from the same `matlab.unittest.TestCase` in parallel by

```
run(MyTest);
```

If `MyTest` is inherited from `matlab.unittest.TestCase`.

How to run multiple `matlab.unittest.TestCase` classes in parallel?

Comment: That will run all of the tests defined in the class but as far as I know, they aren't run in parallel. The only way to run them in parallel would be to run your tests in your `TestSuite` one at a time within a `parfor` loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you have R2015a or later you can use the [runInParallel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testrunner.runinparallel.html) method of the TestRunner. If you have R2015b or beyond access to that is even easier with the runtests [‘UseParallel’ option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/runtests.html#namevaluepairarguments).

Also, even if you have earlier versions, these blog posts describe how this can be done along with various scheduling tradeoffs:

[Encouragingly Parallel - Part 1](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/02/20/encouragingly-parallel-part-1/)

[Encouragingly Parallel - Part 2](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/03/03/encouragingly-parallel-part-2/)

[Encouragingly Parallel - Part 3](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/03/13/encouragingly-parallel-epilogue/)

Comment: This requires Parallel Computing Toolbox.

Comment: Yes indeed. The UseParallel option of runtests can be called with or without Parallel Computing Toolbox, but without the toolbox the suite will be run serially.

Comment: Ultimately the Test array can be run individually or collectively. If you want to handle scheduling yourself you can certainly run subsets the test array, for example in 4 or 8 different MATLAB sessions. However, I think that may be too difficult for practical usage, and that is what Parallel Computing Toolbox is built to solve.